# Why HTML file that I got from Google Translate using my script, is different from what I really want?

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to make a web scraper that will automatically take the translation of a word from Google Translate, in my console environment using my python script.

I saw that HTML code which I got from python `Requests` module, is very different from what it is on the website, you can see the [differences](https://www.diffchecker.com/5NfF30hG).

After some researches about this subject, I learned [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14339352/12532854) that Google has some security features that won't let me have access to its HTML contents using my scripts.

But I have a chrome extension `ImTranslator`, which can give me translate of whatever word I selected from a web page, directly from Google Translate.

So, how this extension can do this?! Why I can't have a script that will do this for me?

I also tried using `urllib` for making requests and sending headers with my request.

Also, this is my code:

First, using `urllib` module:

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}
url = 'https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fa&text=space'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers)
respone = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Second, using `Requests`:

```
url = 'https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=fa&text=space'
res = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: You have to use Google API to do this types of requests.

Comment: You have to show us your code, and the result that you got, and the result you expected.

Comment: @fez.tival-QnPolice Ok, I added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) module of Python to translate some text through free API.

But if you want to scrape the Google Translate then you can do the following

```
import requests_html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hy&text={}"

text = input("text: ")

with requests_html.HTMLSession() as session:
    response = session.get(url.format(text))
    response.html.render()
    content = response.html.html
    soup = BS(content, "html.parser")
    translation = soup.find("span", "translation").text
    print(translation)
```

Using **asynchronous** programming

```
import asyncio
import pyppeteer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

URL = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=hy&text={}"

async def main() -> None:
    text = input("text to translate: ")
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch(headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(URL.format(text))
    html = await page.content()
    soup = BS(html, "html.parser")
    tranlation = soup.find("span", "translation").text
    print(tranlation)
    await browser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It Works!! but, can you explain the first code? I have no idea how did that work! I tried to find other elements from the web page but I can't.

Comment: First I get html content then I rendered JS because Google Translate used JS for its dynamic frontned. After it I get full content of that page and parsed it